# Convert HttpCookieCollection to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, httpcookie, namevaluecollection

My objective is to store all `request(*QueryString,Form,Headers,Cookies*)` information to a single `NameValueCollection`.

Here is my code so far

```
var mainNVC = new NameValueCollection();
mainNVC.Add(context.Request.Form); //works
mainNVC.Add(context.Request.Headers); //works
mainNVC.Add(context.Request.QueryString); //works
mainNVC.Add(context.Request.Cookies); // error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpCookieCollection' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'
```

Tried using `Request.Param` however, I don't want the server variables to be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work because `Request.Cookies` is of type `HttpCookieCollection`. 
You'll need to convert it to a `NameValueCollection`.

You can create an extension method called `ToNameValueCollection()`:

```
public static class CookieCollectionExtensions
{
    public static NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection(
          this HttpCookieCollection cookieCollection)
    {
        var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach (var key in cookieCollection.AllKeys)
        {
            nvc.Add(key, cookieCollection[key].Value);
        }

        return nvc;
    }
}
```

And then when you add the `Cookies`:

```
mainNVC.Add(context.Request.Cookies.ToNameValueCollection());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 
`nvc.Add(key, cookieCollection[key].Value);` ?
And maybe a check for null?